# Customize Flash Player controller using Javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, flash

I wonder if its possible to remove or customize on some parts of the flash player controller.
I have an embed tag, that would generate a video from Ustream. The case is there is a share button and I don't want it to be there. Currently the streaming provider does not allow users to disable it.

[image]

I also tried it playing the video on a jwplayer, but they don't support it, it's because of some crossdomain restrictions. So I'm thinking if Javascript has the ability to remove the button for me. If not, can anyone give me some alternatives?

Here's my generated embed tag

```
<object width="320" height="260">
<param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;vid=1234" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="src" value="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" />
<embed 
    flashvars="autoplay=false&amp;vid=1234" 
    width="320" 
    height="260" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" 
    src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</object>
```

Comment: @JcFx about that, it's because the answers was way later when I posted the questions. And I was not able to track back and check those answers because I haven't been back here for a while. But thanks for reminding, I'm checking them now.

Comment: all good. Somebody pointed out I should improve mine, and they were right, so I'm just passing wisdom along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the button through JavaScript unless the player has some kind of `ExternalInterface` API for you to work with (unlikely). You could load their entire player inside another swf of your own, for example using a Loader component (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html):

```
var url:String = "http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf?autoplay=false&vid=1234";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
ldr.load(urlReq);
addChild(ldr);
```

Once the player has loaded, you will have access to it via the loader's `content` property. How much access may depend on the swf's version and security settings, and you may need to set the security and app domain's of the [LoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) before loading the url request.

Assuming you can get access to the loaded swf, you then need to walk down the tree of DisplayObjects until you find the button you want to hide. This is probably going to be a case of trial and error. Once you get to it, it's just a case of setting `visible=false;`

Alternatively, you could use CSS to position a bit of coloured DIV over the top of the button. That's not likely to look very good, though.